# listview cell not updating using data binding

Tags: listview, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, listviewitem

I binded the item source and the data. The data does change but the UI does not reflect the changes.

I noticed whenever `TestUpdateCell` is called, `SetProperty(ref items, value)` is not call either. But if I add this statements at the end of `TestUpdateCell`:

```
var temp = Items;
Items = new List<Item>();
Items = temp;
```

`SetProperty(ref items, value)` is call but the UI does not reflect the changes.

Also, I tried using ObservableCollection instead of List and using Xamarin's documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

**Edited to include solution(solution proposed by Gerald Versluis)**

**Solution: Item class**

```
public class Item : MvvmHelpers.ObservableObject
    {           
        string name;
        public string Name      
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { SetProperty(ref name, value); }
        }
    }
```

**Problem:** Item class:

```
public class Item : MvvmHelpers.ObservableObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Item data class:

```
public class ItemData : List<Item>
{
    public ItemData()
    {
        Add(new Item
        {
            Name = "Item One"
        });

        Add(new Item
        {
            Name = "Item Two"
        });

        Add(new Item
        {
            Name = "Item Three"
        });
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class ItemViewModel : MvvmHelpers.BaseViewModel
    {
        public ItemViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ItemData();
        }

        List<Item> items;
        public List<Item> Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set { SetProperty(ref items, value); }
        }

        public void TestUpdateCell()
        {
            Items[0].Name = "Item One Updated";
        }
    }
```

Item page cs:

```
    public class ItemPage : ContentPage
    {
        ItemViewModel ivm;
        public ItemPage()
        {
            BindingContext = ivm = new ItemViewModel();
        }

        void ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {       
            ivm.TestUpdateCell();
        }
}
```

itempage.XAML:

```
ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    ItemTapped="ItemTapped"  >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <view:MyItemView/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView
```

MyItemView:

```
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject;assembly=MyProject"
    x:Class="MyProject.MyItemView">
    <local:CardFrame 
        IsClippedToBounds="True"
        HasShadow="True" >
        <StackLayout 
            Spacing="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid 
                RowSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <local:MyLabel 
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                    FontSize="18"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <!-- omitted rows and columns -->
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </local:CardFrame>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Instead of a List<T> use ObservableCollection<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I see correctly, you have now implemented the property changed mechanism on the list with items. While you want to change a value *within* a item.

Implement the property changed (also) in the `Item` class.

If you want to have cells being added and removed dynamically, put them in a `ObservableCollection`. But again; it is important to note here; that only observes changes in the list itself, not inside the list items.

Comment: Thank you that's what I was missing.